# How to add a condition to exclude when using apply a function

Tags: r

Say I have data in this format:

```
   playerID sp rp c 1b 2b 3b ss of dh primary
1  adamja01  0 31 0  4  0  0  0  0  0      RP
2 adamsau02  0  2 0  0  0  1  3  0  0      RP
3 adamsch01  1  2 0  6  0  0  0  0  0      RP
4 alberma01  0 34 0  0  0  0  0  0  0      RP
5 alcansa01  6  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0      SP
6 alcanvi01  0 27 0  0  0  0  0  0  0      RP
```

I need to create a new column that is a string. The string lists any column names for which there is a value over some threshold for a given row.

Assuming the thresholds are stored in a vector `posThresh`, I can get almost what I want using:

```
positions$altPos <- apply(positions[, 2:10], 1, function(x) 
  toString(names(positions)[2:10][x >= posThresh]))
```

This function adds this column:

```
     playerID sp rp  c 1b 2b 3b ss of dh  primary altPos
1    adamja01  0 31  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       RP     RP
2   adamsau02  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       RP     RP
3   adamsch01  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       RP  SP,RP
4   alberma01  0 34  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       RP     RP
5   alcansa01  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       SP     SP
6   alcanvi01  0 27  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       RP     RP
```

In the case of line 3, the value under `primary` is now repeated under `altPos`.  However, the `RP` value under `altPos` is not coming from `primary` but rather the column name `rp`.  Is there a way I can generate the same information but exclude any value from the string that is equal to `primary`'s value?

Basically, any column that exceeds the threshold and is not also equal to `primary`... I just can't get the formatting down: `>= threshold && <> primary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt your function like this.

```
posThresh <- 1

positions$altPos <- 
  apply(positions, 1, 
        function(x) {
          raw <- names(positions)[2:10][x[2:10] >= posThresh]
          excl <- tolower(as.character(x[grep("primary", names(positions))]))
          cln <- toString(raw[raw != excl])
          if (cln == "") return(NA)
          else return(cln)
        })
```

***Yields***

```
> positions
   playerID sp rp c X1b X2b X3b ss of dh primary  altPos
1  adamja01  0 31 0   4   0   0  0  0  0      RP     X1b
2 adamsau02  0  2 0   0   0   1  3  0  0      RP X3b, ss
3 adamsch01  1  2 0   6   0   0  0  0  0      RP sp, X1b
4 alberma01  0 34 0   0   0   0  0  0  0      RP    <NA>
5 alcansa01  6  0 0   0   0   0  0  0  0      SP    <NA>
6 alcanvi01  0 27 0   0   0   0  0  0  0      RP    <NA>
```

#### Edit:

The function above is already working with `posThresh` vectors. Below is a function that also works with matrices. It would be wise to include some exception handling, which I've done.

```
validThresh <- function(positions, posThresh) {
  stopifnot(all(!is.na(posThresh)))
  if(!length(posThresh) == 1 & !is.matrix(posThresh) &
     !length(posThresh) == dim(positions[2:10])[2])
    stop("length of posThresh do not equal number of test columns!")
  if(!all(is.matrix(posThresh) & dim(posThresh) == dim(positions[2:10])))
    stop("posThresh and test matrix do not have the same dimensions!")
  mx <- positions[2:10] >= posThresh
  raw <- apply(mx, 1, function(mx) names(mx[mx == TRUE]))
  excl <- tolower(unlist(positions[grep("primary", names(positions))]))
  cln <- sapply(1:length(raw), function(i) 
    toString(raw[[i]][raw[[i]] != excl[i]]))
  return(ifelse(cln == "", NA, cln))
}
```

*Usage:*

```
validThresh(positions, posThresh)
```

*Some tests:*

```
validThresh(positions, posThresh=1)
validThresh(positions, posThresh=NA)  # error
validThresh(positions, posThresh=c(6, 27, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1))
validThresh(positions, posThresh=c(1, 2, 2))  # error
validThresh(positions, posThresh=matrix(1, 6, 9))
validThresh(positions, posThresh=matrix(1, 7, 9))  # error
```

Finally add your column like this:

```
positions$altPos <- validThresh(positions, posThresh)
```

#### Data

```
positions <- structure(list(playerID = structure(1:6, .Label = c("adamja01", 
"adamsau02", "adamsch01", "alberma01", "alcansa01", "alcanvi01"
), class = "factor"), sp = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L), rp = c(31L, 
2L, 2L, 34L, 0L, 27L), c = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1b = c(4L, 
0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2b = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X3b = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ss = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), of = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dh = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), primary = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("RP", "SP"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is there any way to make `posThresh` a vector with length 9, equal to the number of columns? Basically so each position can have a different number?

Comment: Wasn't that already working with vectors? I've added a function that also works with matrices, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're amenable to using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, then

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(k, v, -playerID, -primary) %>%
  filter(v > 0, tolower(primary) != k) %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>%
  summarize(k = paste(k, collapse = ","))
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   playerID  k     
#   <fct>     <chr> 
# 1 adamja01  X1b   
# 2 adamsau02 X3b,ss
# 3 adamsch01 sp,X1b
# 4 alberma01 ""    
# 5 alcansa01 ""    
# 6 alcanvi01 ""
```

From here, you can `merge` or `left_join` it back with the original frame.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to help out but this is basically the same thing as what I was doing.  I re-worded the question to add clarity, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you need to define `posThresh`, as there's mention of it but no definition. I think this does most of the work for you, though, since it *does* exclude the `primary` indicator. I'd think `filter(v > 0,` could be replaced with some form of `filter(v > posThresh,` (though I recognize it's a vector ... when you provide it, I might be able to help further).